# ISO table(s) of valid characters for SVG ids

Tags: xml, unicode, svg, identifier

The [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#IDAttribute) refers the reader to the [XML Base spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126) for the characters that may appear in the value of an `id` attribute.

The XML Base spec, however, [does not spell out](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-suggested-names) these characters, AFAICT.  Instead, it makes its recommendations in terms of "Unicode properties" `ID_Start` and `ID_Continue`.

I am looking for a *table* (or *table****s***) listing *explicitly* those characters that have the `ID_Start` and/or `ID_Continue` properties.

(In case that different applications or XML-based standards may specify their own sets of characters with the `ID_Start` and/or the `ID_Continue` properties, I am interested in HTML5-embeded SVG.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a repo on Github that generates bunch of different tables using Python scripts based on Unicode standard. For example here are tables for `ID_START`, `ID_CONTINUE`, `XID_START`, `XID_CONTINUE` etc: https://github.com/sourtin/libucd/blob/master/src/tables/bool.rs

Edit: I think they are parsed from XML databases provided in: http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.2.0/ucdxml/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the allowed character range is defined :

An attribute value is:

```
AttValue   ::= '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
               |  "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-AttValue

A Reference is:

```
Reference    ::=    EntityRef | CharRef
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Reference

CharRef bring us to Char here:

```
Char   ::=    #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]    /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Char

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not address my question, AFAICT.  For one thing, an "id attribute" is not *any* attribute...

Comment: Are you speaking of "Values of type ID MUST match the Name production." in http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#id ?

Comment: I've revised my post to clarify what I'm talking about (namely, http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-suggested-names)