# Chrome 63 - SVG href identifier with umlaut won't be displayed

Tags: google-chrome, svg, chromium

SVG elements which have umlauts in their ids and are referenced by an `use` element won't be displayed in Chrome 63.

Chrome 62 (and prior versions), Firefox 57 and Edge are displaying the SVG correctly.

**Example which won't display the SVG in Chrome 63:**

```html
<svg id="TextBoxA" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 230 110" width="230" height="110"  encoding="UTF-8" >
 <defs>
  <g id="ThisIsAnUmlautä">
   <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="230" height="110" version="1.1">
    <path d="M0,0 h230 v110 l-230,0 z" fill="#444444"></path>
    <path d="M3,3 h224 v104 l-224,0 z" fill="#d13d73"></path>
    <text x="25" y="89" style="fill: #000000; stroke: none; font-size: 88px;">Aüöä</text>
   </svg>
  </g>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <use href="#ThisIsAnUmlautä" opacity="1"></use>
 </g>
</svg>
```

**Working example without umlaut in id:**

```html
<svg id="TextBoxA" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 230 110" width="230" height="110"  encoding="UTF-8" >
 <defs>
  <g id="ThisIsAnUmlaut">
   <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="230" height="110" version="1.1">
    <path d="M0,0 h230 v110 l-230,0 z" fill="#444444"></path>
    <path d="M3,3 h224 v104 l-224,0 z" fill="#d13d73"></path>
    <text x="25" y="89" style="fill: #000000; stroke: none; font-size: 88px;">Aüöä</text>
   </svg>
  </g>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <use href="#ThisIsAnUmlaut" opacity="1"></use>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792848

**Question**

As pointed out in the comments, the intention of the change can probably only be answered by one of the Chromium developers.

It would be helpful to know if umlauts are allowed at all as SVG ids (now confirmed answer here: [ISO table(s) of valid characters for SVG ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550302/iso-tables-of-valid-characters-for-svg-ids)).

So for now does anybody know if there is a workaround for this issue, apart from removing the umlauts?

Comment: @RobertLongson I've added the specific question

Comment: You’d need a chrome developer to respond to the bug report to confirm whether it’s intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in chromium. My bug report was merged into https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=779420.

The chromium developers stated that this bug is already fixed and will be released with Chrome 64.

Until then only a workaround which replaces all umlauts or avoiding umlauts at all can help.